# OpenBSD GCC Upgrade

Tags: command-line, gcc, openbsd, shared-library, opensource-projects

I'm attempting to upgrade the GCC library in OpenBSD from 4.2.1 to 11.2.0 (for a project, and a personal challenge).  So far, everywhere I looked was unsuccessful.  I know it's probably something simple, but I don't know.

Comment: Most OpenBSD architectures no longer ship with GCC installed by default. Your question (like your previous ones) lacks information.  What OpenBSD  are you running, on what architecture, are you using packages or are you trying to compile GCC from sources, what failures do you get (when doing what) and what does "GCC library" mean?

Comment: OpenBSD Version: 6.9
Architecture: amd64
GCC: GNU Compiler Collection (Link: https://gcc.gnu.org/)
Project: Kaldi install (Link: https://github.com/kaldi-asr/kaldi / http://kaldi-asr.org/)
GUI: N/A
CLI: Yes
Shell: ksh

I believe that's all, for now.  The short version is I want to replace GCC 4.2.1 to GCC 11.2.0.  Problem is it appears to be embedded - any assistance would be appreciated.

Comment: When asked for clarifications, please don't respond in comments, but edit your post to include the requested information. Reading through the comments is rather painful, and comments are subject to removal without notice by moderators.

Answer (score 1):

At the time of writing, GCC-11.2.0 is available for installation as a package for all major architectures.  Please read the [appropriate OpenBSD FAQ section](http://www.openbsd.org/faq/faq15.html) for details on using the package system.